# Method annotated with @Cacheable not getting intercepted

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I am new to Spring caching. I am using spring-boot-starter-1.4.0.RELEASE in my maven pom. As far as I understand the documentation, if I take something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class TestApplication {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        // configure and return an implementation of Spring's CacheManager SPI
        SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
        cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("default")));
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MyService myService() {
        // configure and return a class having @Cacheable methods
        return new MyService();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(TestConfiguration.class);
        MyService ms = ctx.getBean(MyService.class);
        ms.doCacheableOperation(); // calls the underlying method
        ms.doCacheableOperation(); // SHOULD just consult the cache
    }
}
```

And have a class like this:

```
public class MyService {
    @Cacheable
    public String doCacheableOperation() {
        System.out.println("======================CALLING EXPENSIVE METHOD=======================");
        return "done";
    }
}
```

When the main method runs in TestApplication, the first call to MyServce#doCacheableOperation should output to the screen, but the second should not since the result would be cached from the first time. This, however, is not the case; the output shows twice.

The configuration code is lifted from the Javadoc for EnableCaching: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html

One thing that does puzzle me is that when I debug and inspect the instance of MyService, it is just the raw object, not wrapped in any CGLib subclass, etc.

How do I need to change my configuration/approach so that the result of MyService#doCacheableOperation is cached?

Answer (score 2):

Oh, boy. Found it. There was a simple typo in the class I was sending to SpringApplication#run:

```
SpringApplication.run(TestConfiguration.class)
```

should have been

```
SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class)
```

Everything seems to be in order now!