# Why @Cacheable doesn't work after second time method invoked

Tags: spring, spring-cache

Figure out that cacheable doesn't work for me, because methods with @Cacheable annotations are inside classes with such structure.
I have

```
public interface Filter<T> {
    List<T> filter(int limit);
}
```

and bunch of implementations:

```
@Component
public class UpcomingFilter implements Filter<Entity> {

    @Cacheable(value = {"upcoming"})
    @Override
    public List<Entity> filter(int limit) {
       //retrieve from repository
    }
}

@Component
public class RecentlyAddedFilter implements Filter<Entity> {
@Cacheable(value = {"recentlyAdded"})
    @Override
    public List<Entity> filter(int limit) {
       //retrieve from repository
    }
}
//and 6 more implementations
```

To optimize Autowiring of this filters, I use HashMap, where I hold this filters:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean("filtersMap")
    public Map<String, Filter> filters() {
        Map<String, Filter> filtersMap = new HashMap<>();

        filtersMap.put("upcomingFilter", new UpcomingFilter(sessionRepository));
        filtersMap.put("recentlyAddedFilter", new RecentlyAddedFilter(entityRepository));
        //..another filters
        return filtersMap;
    }

    }
```

And this map I autowire in my service layer:

```
@Qualifier("filtersMap") Map<String, Filter> filterMap
```

Cache Configuration:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        String[] cacheNames = new String[] {"upcoming", "recentlyAdded"};
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(cacheNames);
    }

}
```

And I do sysout in every filter method and measure time of execution.
It shows that cacheable methods invoked every time, and cache is not used. 
Than I create simple class **MyFilter** without implementing **Filter** interface, 
annotate its method with **@Cacheable** and it works like a charm.
So, how to solve this issue that cache is not works for Classes that implements **Filter** interface

Comment: Is not clear where are you calling your filter method. But as a rule of thumb when you call annotated methods from within the same class they wont apply the annotation. Why? Because annotations are implemented as proxy classes and calls inside the same class dont go to the proxy but to the actual class.

Comment: Hi Nikolas :)) Since you have created a `CacheManager` bean, try to add the bean returning the `CustomerDataService`.

Comment: Hi Nikolas :)) What is the CustomerDataService?

Comment: DON'T manually instantiate beans! You will not get any benefits of Spring. Create `@Bean` methods for each instance and then autowire them into your `filtersMap` method. Or, better yet, just use `getBeansOfType` and don't build the `Map` yourself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider that has nothing to do with what im mentioning. if you have clas A with methods b and c annotated with cacheable and inside method b you call method c it wont hit the cache. Because the way annotations work internally.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by this link [Method annotated with @Cacheable not getting intercepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047139/method-annotated-with-cacheable-not-getting-intercepted?rq=1)
and by Nikolas comment:

add Service bean which has @Cacheable annotation to Cache Configuration class:

```
@EnableCaching
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        String[] cacheNames = new String[] {"upcoming", "recentlyAdded"};
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(cacheNames);
    }

    @Bean
    public PopularFilter popularFilter() {
        return new PopularFilter(myRepository);
    }

     @Bean("filtersMap")
public Map<String, Filter> filters() {
    Map<String, Filter> filtersMap = new HashMap<>();
    filtersMap.put("popularFilter", popularFilter());
    //...
    return filtersMap;
}
```

Comment: But how can I update this Cache with @CachePut in this method:
 @CachePut(value={"upcoming", "popular", "recentlyAdded", "recommendations"})
    public Entity addEntity(RequestDto dto, User user) {/*some code*/}
Cahe is not updated with it.